# How to create an extension on Swift Array to replace nil with a value?

Tags: arrays, swift

I tried the following but I continued to get an array of optional, which I do not want even though I am using compactMap.

```
let numbers: [Int?] = [2, 4, 5, nil, 8]

extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func replacingNil(with element: Element) -> [Element] {
        self.compactMap { $0 == nil ? element : $0 }
    }
}
print(numbers.replaceNil(with: 0))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of `compactMap` is incorrect here. `compactMap` turns a `[T]` to another `[U]` - it is the *mapping function* that is allowed to return an optional (`(T) -> U?`), and it removes any element for which this function returns nil. This property can be used to remove `nil`s from a `[T?]` and get a `[T]` by passing it `{ $0 }`, but that's not what you are trying to do with the `[T?]` in this case.

What you want here is to turn a `[T?]` to `[T]`, and you have a one-to-one mapping, which can be done with a `map` like this:

```
extension Sequence {
    func replacingNil<T>(with element: T) -> [T] where Element == T? {
        self.map { $0 ?? element }
    }
}
```

Comment: `replace` should be used for mutating methods. This should be called `replacingNil`. I would also extend Sequence instead of Array

Comment: I think your generic param T is unnecessary. You can just use `Element?` directly